# Google Apps Script dynamically bulleted list in an html file from Gsheet

Tags: javascript, html, variables, google-apps-script, bulletedlist

I would like to create a dynamically bulleted list in an html file from a google apps-script with variable.
and for this I would like to have some helps as I'm really new on this.
at this moments mail email as fixed op[x] variables therefore if they are empty I have empty bullet list.

I have the function called `luli`
I have variables in an array call operation expecting to be the bulleted list
actually I have also created a countable variable of the sum of them

### luli.gs

```js
function luli() {
  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('INTERVENTION-EMAIL');
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Template Creation');
  // for bulleted list
  var operation = ws.getRange('B27:B32').getValues();
  var i = ws.getRange('$B$33').getValue();
  // used at the moment
  var op1 = wsSettings.getRange('$B$27').getValue();
  var op2 = wsSettings.getRange('$B$28').getValue();
  var op3 = wsSettings.getRange('$B$29').getValue();
  var op4 = wsSettings.getRange('$B$30').getValue();

  //email variables used at the moment
  emailTemp.op1 = op1;
  emailTemp.op2 = op2;
  emailTemp.op3 = op3;
  emailTemp.op4 = op4;

  var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();

  GmailApp.createDraft(
    mail,
    sujet,

    //send  message generated htmlbody & htmlmessage built.
    { name: nom, htmlBody: htmlMessage, cc: cc, from: from },
  );
}
```

I have an email template called **intervention-email**

### intervention-email.html

```html
<p dir="ltr">
  <span style="font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
    ><?= corps1 ?></span
  >
</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: square">
  <li dir="ltr">
    <span
      style="
        font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10pt;
      "
      ><?= op1 ?></span
    >
  </li>
  <li dir="ltr">
    <span
      style="
        font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10pt;
      "
      ><?= op2 ?></span
    >
  </li>
  <li dir="ltr">
    <span
      style="
        font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10pt;
      "
      ><?= op3 ?></span
    >
  </li>
  <li dir="ltr">
    <span
      style="
        font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10pt;
      "
      ><?= op4 ?></span
    >
  </li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

It will be nice to have a code generating the li bulleted list according to the information contenned in the operation variable then populating the email list.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail where exactly you struggle and need help? What is the problem with your code as it is?

Comment: I have static li html code each li is a variable op1 to op4 if I have all of them it's good because it fills them all. But if i have only one i have 3 bullets empty. It will be nicer if i can generate the right number of bullets with the right operations. maybe by having a loop for each or something similar ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can push your variables into an array (or directly retrieve them as an array) and then pass the array to the template

Sample

*Code.gs*

```js
...
var values = wsSettings.getRange('B27:B30').getValues().flat();
emailTemp.options = values;
var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
...
```

*intervention-email.html*

```js
...
<ul style="list-style-type: square">
<? for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) { ?>
  <li dir="ltr">
    <span style="font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt;">
      <?= options[i] ?>
    </span>
  </li>
<? } ?>
</ul>
...
```

See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates).

Comment: Parfait ! it's working , thank you for your quick answer !

Comment: I forgot to say that there is a typo error  in your "for" sentence the variable is only "i" there s no "j" expected.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I edited it in my response!

Comment: No prob, i'm using the code and it's good to have it working !